# Передача данных с DataGrid в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть TextBox на одной форме

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и по нажатию на кнопку "..." открывается другая форма с DataGrid.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно с выделенной строки грида вытянуть данные и перенести в TextBox.
Я сделал как-то костыльно:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListPerson listPerson = new ListPerson();
    listPerson.ShowDialog();
    textBox1.Text = listPerson.infoPersonDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value 
    + "," + listPerson.infoPersonDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value + ", " +
    listPerson.infoPersonDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value;
}
```

Есть какие-то варианты сделать по другому, более эстетично?)

Comment: `textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", listPerson.infoPersonDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells.Select(x=>x.Value))`.

Comment: Ошибка CS1061 "DataGridViewCellCollection" не содержит определения для "Select", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Select", принимающий тип "DataGridViewCellCollection" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: Почитайте про пространства имен и научитесь их находить. [Select это LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: спасибо за инфу

Comment: Я так понял нужно подключить using System.Linq? Если да, то уже подключено, но ошибка остается

Comment: Тогда надо преобразовать в нужный тип. Напишите перед `.Select(...)` что то вроде этого `.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()`. Ваша строка будет тогда примерно такой: `textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", listPerson.infoPersonDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x.Value));`.

Comment: Также в форме `ListPerson` можете создать публичное свойство, которое будет отдавать уже нужный формат выбранных ячеек (что то вроде этого: `public IEnumerable<DataGridViewCell> CurrentCells => infoPersonDataGridView.CurrentRow?.Cells?.OfType<DataGridViewCell>();`) и тогда ваш код будет вообще состоять из `textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", listPerson.CurrentCells.Select(x => x.Value));`. Уже как то "более эстетично" и без необходимости писать `Cells[1...10...15...]`.

Comment: работает, спасибо за помощь! жаль репы нету проголосовать за ответы